# How to create bitly shortened url from user's inputed text?

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

Begginer here, people. Could anybody suggest any kind of solution? I've an user inputed text.
First of all I check if the text has any urls:

```
 $post = preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[\w\-\.!~?&+\*\'"(),\/]+/','<a class="post_link"          
 href="$0">$0</a>',$post);
```

And after that I need to retrieve that url and put as a variable($url) to this function:

```
 $short=make_bitly_url('$url','o_6sgltp5sq4as','R_f5212f1asdads1cee780eed00d2f1bd2fd794f','xml');
```

And finally, echo both url and user's text. Thanks in advance for ideas and critiques.

I've tried something like that:

```
 $post = preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[\w\-\.!~?&+\*\'"(),\/]+/e',$url,$post){
 $shorten = make_bitly_url($url,'o_6sgltpmm5sq4','R_f5212f11cee780ekked00d2f1bd2fd794f','json');
 return '<a class="post_link" href="$shorten">$shorten</a>';
 };
```

But even for me it looks some kind of nonsense.

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do and what have you already tried to achieve said goal?

Comment: @kingkero I've added, what I was trying to do.

Comment: Please upvote any answers that are helpful to you, and choose a correct answer when done (to close the question).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use the bit.ly API from PHP:

```
/* make a URL small */
function make_bitly_url($url,$login,$appkey,$format = 'xml',$version = '2.0.1')
{
    //create the URL
    $bitly = 'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version='.$version.'&longUrl='.urlencode($url).'&login='.$login.'&apiKey='.$appkey.'&format='.$format;

    //get the url
    //could also use cURL here
    $response = file_get_contents($bitly);

    //parse depending on desired format
    if(strtolower($format) == 'json')
    {
        $json = @json_decode($response,true);
        return $json['results'][$url]['shortUrl'];
    }
    else //xml
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        return 'http://bit.ly/'.$xml->results->nodeKeyVal->hash;
    }
}

/* usage */
$short = make_bitly_url('http://davidwalsh.name','davidwalshblog','R_96acc320c5c423e4f5192e006ff24980','json');
echo 'The short URL is:  '.$short; 

// returns:  http://bit.ly/11Owun
```

[Source: David Walsh article](http://davidwalsh.name/bitly-php)

---

HOWEVER, if you wanted to create your own URL shortening system (similar to bit.ly -- and surprisingly easy to do), here is an 8-part tutorial from [PHPacademy](http://phpacademy.org/) on how to do that:

Difficulty level: beginner / intermediate

Each video is approx ten minutes.

[Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHsHteIjCsI)
[Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FgkcbRagtw)
[Part 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNzTO5FxghI)
[Part 4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0AYHzmZ6Kk)
[Part 5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USOb7xrdsDY)
[Part 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWXzzCOSTpo)
[Part 7](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECeAYhP67tE)
[Part 8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJMHXvWVUuY)

Comment: Well, I know how to create bit.ly urls etc. The question is how to get that preg_replace function generated url from user text and pass it to bit.ly function and then return both shorten url and the text. But anyway thanks, for source :)

Answer (score 1):

Bitly does have an API available for use. You should check out [API Documentation](http://dev.bitly.com/api.html)

Comment: @Izodn I've checked. And as I understood, first of all I need to get that url from string and then pass it to bit.ly.